# $\mathcal{I}\vDash \alpha$ if and only if $\mathcal{I}\vDash\forall x\alpha$ in FOL

Tags: first-order-logic

> For any interpretation $\mathcal{I}$ and wff $\alpha$, prove that $\mathcal{I}\vDash \alpha$ if and only if $\mathcal{I}\vDash\forall x\alpha$. Moreover if $\alpha^*$ denotes the closure of $\alpha(x_1,...,x_n)$ i.e. $\alpha^* = \forall x_1...\forall x_n$, we have $\mathcal{I}\vDash \alpha$ if and only if $\mathcal{I}\vDash \alpha^*$

**Here's my work:**

1. One direction seems simple, i.e. $\mathcal{I}\vDash \alpha$ implies $\mathcal{I}\vDash \forall x\alpha$. By definition, $\mathcal{I}\vDash \alpha$ means $\mathcal{I},v\vDash \alpha$ ($v$ satisfies $\alpha$ in $\mathcal{I}$) for all valuations $v$ in $\mathcal{I}$. For an arbitrary valuation $v_0$, $\mathcal{I},v_0\vDash\forall x\alpha$ iff for each valuation $v_0'$ that is $x$-equivalent to $v_0$, $\mathcal{I},v_0\vDash \alpha$. This is true since $\mathcal{I},v\vDash \alpha$ for all $v$. Hence, $\mathcal{I}\vDash\forall x\alpha$.
2. I started with $\mathcal{I}\vDash\forall x\alpha$, which by definition means that $\mathcal{I},v\vDash\forall x\alpha$ for all valuations $v$ in $\mathcal{I}$. For a particular $v$, we know that $\mathcal{I},v\vDash\forall x\alpha$ iff for all $v'$ $x$-equivalent to $v$, we have $\mathcal{I},v'\vDash \alpha$ (this holds for all $v$). How do I take it from here?

I think once "$\mathcal{I}\vDash \alpha$ if and only if $\mathcal{I}\vDash\forall x\alpha$" is proved, the statement concerning $\alpha$ and $\alpha^*$ is obvious! I'd appreciate any help, thanks!

**For reference (some definitions):**

1. Two valuations $v,v'$ are $x$-equivalent if they match on all variables but $x$, i.e. $v(y)=v'(y)$ for all $y\neq x$.
2. $\mathcal{I}\vDash \alpha$ means $\mathcal{I},v\vDash \alpha$ ($v$ satisfies $\alpha$ in $\mathcal{I}$) for all $v$ in $\mathcal{I}$.
3. $\mathcal{I},v\vDash\forall x\alpha$ iff $\mathcal{I},v'\vDash\alpha$ for all $v'$ $x$-equivalent to $v$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured it out! Since $v$ is $x$-equivalent to itself, putting $v' = v$ in (2) does the trick.